# Can I use NLB to balance multiple sites on the same (n) servers?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6, load-balancing, nlb

I know this is probably a simple question, but I can't seem to find a definitive answer anywhere.  We have two servers (Win2K3 SP1) running a single website on IIS 6.0 under NLB.  Each server is running two network adapters, currently with one handling the "normal" server traffic, and the other handling the NLB cluster serving the single website.  I'm wondering if it's possible and/or advisable to run multiple websites in IIS under different NLB clusters on the same two servers.  If it is possible, does anyone have a link to anything that describes how to do this correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Your NLB rule should be specific to port 80 so any requests for any web site on port 80 should be handled by NLB. Just make sure that you have an external DNS A or CNAME record for the new site that points to the public ip address of the web server. In IIS you can then add host headers on each site so that incoming requests get routed to the correct web site.

Edit: You don't need multiple NLB clusters. One will do as it will handle all traffic going to port 80. IIS will differentiate between the web sites based on the host headers.

Comment: Ok, so in this case, we need a single "virtual IP" for each site within the cluster, which points at each server's dedicated IP on port 80.  Then IIS can take care of the rest.  Thanks!